# Cannot open source device in random_bytes() Laravel PHP 7.0

Tags: php, laravel, php-7

I visite many forum, but i can't find the best solution for my problems. 
In laravel 5, i have this error :

```
Cannot open source device in random_bytes() : 
Exception in Str.php line 243:
Cannot open source device
in Str.php line 243
at random_bytes('25') in Str.php line 243
at Str::randomBytes('25') in Str.php line 227
at Str::random('25') in Store.php line 197
at Store->generateSessionId() in Store.php line 173
```

The str.php is in : httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php
at :

```
/**
 * Generate a more truly "random" alpha-numeric string.
 *
 * @param  int  $length
 * @return string
 */
public static function random($length = 16)
{
    $string = '';

    while (($len = strlen($string)) < $length) {
        $size = $length - $len;

        $bytes = static::randomBytes($size);

        $string .= substr(str_replace(['/', '+', '='], '', base64_encode($bytes)), 0, $size);
    }

    return $string;
}

/**
 * Generate a more truly "random" bytes.
 *
 * @param  int  $length
 * @return string
 */
public static function randomBytes($length = 16)
{
    return random_bytes($length);
}
```

i use php 7. I also change random_bytes by openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(), it's work but i have another error that the framework can't generate hash for password. So i think openssl_random_bytes is not the best solution.

If someone can help.

Thanks

Comment: What exact version of PHP 7 are you using?

Comment: This : 
# php -v
PHP 7.0.19 (cli) (built: May 12 2017 21:01:27) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies

Comment: I had a similar issue and a lot of segfaults, I performed an upgrade to PHP 7.1.1 and they work fine now.

Comment: I install PHP 7.1.5, but i have same error :

PHP 7.1.5 (cli) (built: May 12 2017 21:54:58) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.5, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies

Answer (score 0):

From `random_bytes` [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php):

> The sources of randomness used for this function are as follows:
>
> - On Windows, **» CryptGenRandom()** will always be used.
> - On Linux, the » getrandom(2) syscall will be used if available.
> - On other platforms, `/dev/urandom` will be used.
> - If none of the aforementioned sources are available, then an Exception will be thrown.

So, your case is last one. It's not your code problem, but server settings. What is the environment? Hosting, cloud, virtual server, local machine?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i use vps : CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
So i will check /dev/uradom...

Comment: I make a test with : # < /dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c${1:-32};echo; 
I have this response : 
axwH4GdEnIbKnPfpwNu-gQRasae3VWAV